# JMeter command line: Can I output the run log to STDOUT?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, stdout, jmeter

I just want the JMeter run log (-l parameter) piped to STDOUT for processing in a script, is there an easy way to do this? Using /tmp files is so icky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

didn't try it, but may be `JMeter -l /dev/stdout` will help?

Comment: Oh, brilliant idea, I didn't realize I could write to /dev/stdout, in any case I learned a very useful feature today. There's still some extra stuff that jmeter writes on stdout that I'm not sure I can eliminate though, so it's looking like a no-go still.

Comment: Can you put the log on stderr and send stdout to /dev/null?

Comment: /dev/stdout works fine with -j option as well

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [`mkfifo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe):

```
$ mkfifo log.txt
$ cat log.txt | ./script.sh
$ JMeter -l log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess this is the best I can do, but it's not different than a /tmp file, so I guess I'm stuck with having to create and clean up something on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `-j /dev/stdout` as per this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71508222/2303693