# Jmeter CLI option to print logs in the Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

Just curious whether we can get the jmeter logs printed in Jenkins console. This is what I am using in Jenkins to run the Jmeter

```
    sh "/home/jenkins/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter.sh -f -n -t my.jmx -l output.jtl -j jmeter.log -p my.properties -e -o results"
    archiveArtifacts '**/jmeter.log'
```

Above can generate the logfile and archive.
My requirement is to see them in Jenkins console logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding `-j /dev/stdout` switch to your command line, as per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

> -j, --jmeterlogfile  jmeter run log file (jmeter.log)

and `/dev/stdout` is a [Linux device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) providing read/write access to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) standard stream

Alternatively you can [amend JMeter's logging configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) and add one more [appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender) to print the log messages to the STDOUT as well.

And last but not the least [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: I tried this `sh "/home/jenkins/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter.sh -f -n -t my.jmx -l /dev/stdout -j jmeter.log -p my.properties -e -o results"` and got below Jenkins console error. Is that something related to access?                                                                               `Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not delete results file /dev/stdout(canRead:true, canWrite:true) `

Comment: apologies, it was a typo, it supposed to be `-j`